# Counting/autofill in a text file

Tags: bash, automation

I have a very easy bash script for linux:

```
blastn -db database -evalue 1e-5 -query 001.fasta -out 001.blast.txt -best_hit_overhang 0.1 -best_hit_score_edge 0.1 -outfmt 6 -max_target_seqs 1 &
blastn -db database -evalue 1e-5 -query 002.fasta -out 002.blast.txt -best_hit_overhang 0.1 -best_hit_score_edge 0.1 -outfmt 6 -max_target_seqs 1
```

I need to do this 360 (001...360) times. Is it possible to autogenerate these lines with "001" going up +1 in every new line? It is basically the same as autofilling in excel (one could do a text to columns, write new lines, then concatenate again). Only the two numbers in -query and -out should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a bash for loop - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

This would be the relevant example from that link

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

So for your example it would look something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..360}
do
  blastn -db database -evalue 1e-5 -query $i.fasta -out $i.blast.txt -best_hit_overhang 0.1 -best_hit_score_edge 0.1 -outfmt 6 -max_target_seqs 1
done
```